# Yii2: /vendor/autoload.php causes error 500

Tags: yii2, installation, composer-php, autoload

I have installed yii2 (I have tried advanced and basic installations and deleted / repeated the process several times). In all instances the autoload line in the index file causes an error 500:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

If I comment out the line above, I do not get the error 500 (although Yii obviously does not work). As soon as I include the line, I get an error 500.

I have reinstalled composer and reinstalled Yii2 but no success.

My only observation is that the alphanumeric below does not seem to match the alphanumeric seen in the /composer/autoload_real.php but I am not sure if it should.

```
return ComposerAutoloaderInit76b6976ae6a0da7190a4d881939374a2::getLoader();
```

Please advise

### UPDATE

- I deleted the composer.phar file
- I deleted the full html directory
- I reinstalled composer
- I reinstalled yii2 basic in html

The same error occurs:
==> error_log <==

```
[Tue Jun 11 04:49:50.851130 2019] [:error] [pid 21494] [client 10.176.18.31:63288] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInit76b6976ae6a0da7190a4d881939374a2' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php on line 7
```

Interestingly, I notice that the alphanumeric 76b6976ae6a0da7190a4d881939374a2 is exactly the same despite reinstalling composer. I am not clear how composer works but I would've presumed this alphanumeric would update?? Is there a cache I am supposed to clear somewhere?

When I view the /vendor/composer/autoload_real.php I see it is called:

```
ComposerAutoloaderInitcc7884a20c85dc8a5213cc9c1a84bc90
```

This does not match the autoloader file and has changed following the re-installation. Again, I am not completely clear how composer works but this seems to be odd.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: look into your server logs for the actual reason causing the error if you are on lice server go to the errors section in the capanel

Comment: Please check your logs. If you are running this in a development environment, you should probably change the php.ini to have `display_errors` enabled

Comment: Here is the error message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInit76b6976ae6a0da7190a4d881939374a2' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php on line 7

Comment: Please update the question with full trace and exception message.

Comment: try to run `composer dump-autoload` and check one more time

Comment: This is automatically generated by Composer as part of the update process, and gets also generated during install. The name of the class is dynamically generated, are you working on live server and pushed the `vendor` folder to live along with the `ComposerAutoloaderInit76b6976ae6a0da7190a4d881939374a2` file? if yes then remove the vendor folder and run  `composer update`

Comment: Hi Muhammad: No, I am not pushing any files up. I am literally installing composer and Yii. Yet somehow the autoload.php maintains the same alphanumeric. I think something must be caching somewhere / somehow. I am going to try Yerke's suggestion and see what happens

Comment: Ok, so Yerke's suggestion works. If I run composer dump-autoload followed by composer update, then the alphanumerics match. However, I am still receiving an Error 500 and I need the IT team to get me the trace. I don't understand what is going on... normally Yii installs without any hassle. More to follow... thanks so far..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Yerke - your suggestion worked perfectly
I simply ran `composer dump-autoload` and then `composer update`

Comment: have a nice day ;)